# List of GPS's compatible with Firefox 3.5?

Tags: firefox, gps

Where can I get a list of GPS's compatible with Firefox 3.5's Location Based Browsing?

Or is there some feature of a GPS that is required for this to work?

Also does it matter which OS Firefox 3.5 is running on?

Comment: What are you planning on using this for?

Comment: @lvo Just so I can mess around with it. *shrugs*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps a better resource: [Geolocation in Firefox](http://en-us.www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/geolocation/) (by Mozilla)

TLDR: no gps is being used

**How does it work?**

> When you visit a location-aware website, Firefox will ask you if you want to share your location.
>
> If you consent, Firefox gathers information about nearby wireless access points and your computer’s IP address. Then Firefox sends this information to the default geolocation service provider, Google Location Services, to get an estimate of your location. That location estimate is then shared with the requesting website.
>
> If you say that you do not consent, Firefox will not do anything.

**How accurate are the locations?**

> Accuracy varies greatly from location
> to location. In some places, our
> service providers may be able to
> provide a location to within a few
> meters. However, in other areas it
> might be much more than that. All
> locations returned by our service
> providers are estimates only and we do
> not guarantee the accuracy of the
> locations provided. Please do not use
> this information for emergencies.
> Always use common sense.

**What information is being sent, and to whom? How is my privacy protected?**

> Your privacy is extremely important to
> us, and Firefox never shares your
> location without your permission. When
> you visit a page that requests your
> information, you’ll be asked before
> any information is shared with the
> requesting website and our third-party
> service provider.
>
> By default, Firefox uses Google
> Location Services to determine your
> location by sending:
>
> - your computer’s IP address,
> - information about the nearby wireless access points, and
> - a random client identifier, which is assigned by Google, that expires
>   every 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a GPS for this.  Loation-based browsing uses your IP address to estimate your location.  See [this article](http://blog.myiptest.com/firefox-location-based-browsing-feature).

Comment: @ChrisEdmonton Right, but you still can right?

Comment: No.  Even if you have a GPS, it will not be used.